# How to get an infinite stream from slick source with java jdbc

Tags: java, slick, akka-stream

am very new to akka.

How can I unfoldAsync this source to get an infinite stream that will always give me 1 record, then the next and so on... with java.

```
final Source<Person, NotUsed> source = Slick.source(
    session,
    "SELECT id,last_name,date_modified FROM akka.people LIMIT 1;",
    (SlickRow row) -> {
    return new Person(row.nextString(), row.nextString(), 0, row.nextString());
    }
);
```

so that I can throttle the records and process one after the next...

```
source.throttle(1, Duration.create(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS), 1, ThrottleMode.shaping())
    .runForeach(x -> {
     //to perform business login here.
    System.out.println(x.toString());
    }, materializer);
```

This currently stops after picking the first row.

Comment: Maybe it will help you if you look closely your `SELECT id,last_name,date_modified FROM akka.people LIMIT 1;` As far as I know every DB will return ONLY the very first row from table. Please note that I didn't read your code after this - so, maybe, I'm wrong. Good luck.

Comment: Hey zlakad, If i don't limit it will still give me the result set stream, then stop, however that's not what I want. lets assume i change the limit to 2, it should pick 2, then the next 2 and so on...

Comment: I see. Perhaps changing the limit clause with something like WHERE id = ...? And managing the next id.

Comment: Why not just remove the `LIMIT 1` part of your query?  It's not clear what you mean by "unfoldAsync this source to get an infinite stream that will always give me 1 record".  You're table can't have an infinite number of rows, so do you just want the same row repeated?